# React router dom not rendering components

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I was loading my page and the content wouldn't show. I think the problem is that my react router dom is not rendering my components.
This is the content I was trying to show:

```
import React from 'react';

const HomePage = () => (
<>
<h1>Hello, welcome to my blog!</h1>
<p>
    Welcome to my blog! Proin congue
    ligula id risus posuere, vel eleifend ex egestas. Sed in turpis leo. 
    Aliquam malesuada in massa tincidunt egestas. Nam consectetur varius turpis, 
    non porta arcu porttitor non. In tincidunt vulputate nulla quis egestas. Ut 
    eleifend ut ipsum non fringilla. Praesent imperdiet nulla nec est luctus, at 
    sodales purus euismod.
</p>
<p>
    Donec vel mauris lectus. Etiam nec lectus urna. Sed sodales ultrices dapibus. 
    Nam blandit tristique risus, eget accumsan nisl interdum eu. Aenean ac accumsan 
    nisi. Nunc vel pulvinar diam. Nam eleifend egestas viverra. Donec finibus     
    sed lorem ultricies, eget ornare leo luctus. Morbi vehicula, nulla eu tempor 
    interdum, nibh elit congue tellus, ac vulputate urna lorem nec nisi. Morbi id 
    consequat quam. Vivamus accumsan dui in facilisis aliquet.,
</p>
<p>
    Etiam nec lectus urna. Sed sodales ultrices dapibus. 
    Nam blandit tristique risus, eget accumsan nisl interdum eu. Aenean ac accumsan 
    nisi. Nunc vel pulvinar diam. Nam eleifend egestas viverra. Donec finibus 
    sed lorem ultricies, eget ornare leo luctus. Morbi vehicula, nulla eu tempor 
    interdum, nibh elit congue tellus, ac vulputate urna lorem nec nisi. Morbi id 
    consequat quam. Vivamus accumsan dui in facilisis aliquet.,
</p>
</>
);

export default HomePage;
```

Here is the code where I was rendering it to but won't show:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Route,Routes
}  from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What version of react-router are you using?

Comment: The newest one.

Comment: Then you need to use the element prop, not the component prop: `<Route path="" element={<HomePage/>}>`